# What is the best approach when trying to use POCO with EF4?

Tags: entity-framework-4, implementation, poco

I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648730/is-my-understanding-of-pocos-entity-framework-v4-correct) 3 approaches towards implementing POCO with entity framework namely

1. Create edmx model and turn off code generation so the model will not create heavy entities for you. Then you will create your POCO classes which have to follow some restrictions.
2. You can use the [POCO template](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/23df0450-5677-4926-96cc-173d02752313) which can be downloaded to VS 2010.
3. Use Code First approach where you code your POCOs and you define mapping in code. To do
   this you need EF 4.0 Feature CTP from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=4e094902-aeff-4ee2-a12d-5881d4b0dd3e).

I was personally going to opt for the second approach as it is quicker but what are the things that I should keep in mind since it derives from ObjectContext I guess it is in a way coupled? I know the third approach gives the most flexibility but is it worth it ? Please share your thoughts regarding this..Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to use CTP in a shared hosting enviroment, if I have no control over what's installed on the host machine? I think this is important to consider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That link you have provided for "POCO Template" is broken - but i assume you mean this:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/23df0450-5677-4926-96cc-173d02752313

This template can (and should) be used in conjuction with Option 1 you have stated.

That's what i use in my current application:

1 - Create EDMX Model

2 - Turn off code gen

3 - Use POCO Generator to generate POCO classes

The POCO's do not derive from anything - they are pure POCO's.

Comment: What do you think about the third option ? Is it worth it ? Also the poco classes context generated derives from `ObjectContext` do you think that is an issue or a drawback?

Comment: I haven't used code first so i can't comment on it. Personally i prefer seeing the model (EDMX). The POCO classes **do not derive from ObjectContext**. This only happens when you use default code generation - they are not POCO's.

Comment: @Misnomer: First of all you don't need to use derived context. You can use ObjectContext directly. Even with CTP you will have class derived from DbContext so I don't see any drawback there. If you don't want to expose these types to your upper layers then check Unit of work and Repositories patterns or define interface on derived ObjectContext and use any IoC container to inject implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I found these two links to be invaluable when setting up my model/poco classes. [Poco generation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/01/25/walkthrough-poco-template-for-the-entity-framework.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0) and [Poco options](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/03/10/poco-template-code-generation-options.aspx). As mentioned above it is a good idea (certainly if using the repository pattern) to turn off code generation in the edmx and create both a derived ObjectContext class and your Poco classes via the two T4 templates provided by Microsoft.

If you use the T4 templates without making any changes to them then you will get a set of Poco classes with the "Change Tracking Proxies with Fixup" option enabled in the generated code.